# Compare only the last three characters of a string

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program that creates new folders and moves the old folder to an archive location.
I need to be able to compare the last three digits of a folder path to see if it's "999", for example a folder will be called "1950-1999" and this will need a new parent folder.

Code so far:

```
Dim stringreader As String
Dim path As List(Of String)

Private Sub Archive_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Loads a text file at the given location, to read to.
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Data\Test\Foldercreation.txt")
    'Set stringreader as the read line from the file
    stringreader = fileReader.ReadLine()

    path = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(stringreader).ToList
    path.Sort()
    foldtoarchtxt.Text = path(0)

    'closes the file
    fileReader.Close()
```

As you can see I have got the folder path and stored it in a list (which is displayed to the user as well hence the text output).

I just don't know how to get VB.NET to always look at the last three digits on the right. One note, this will get to 100000's and maybe even 1000000 i.e. 100950-100999 so it can't be based on position from the left.

Comment: `If path.EndsWith("999")`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

```
If path(0).Substring(path(0).Length - 3)) = "999" Then
    ...
End If
```

As an example:

```
Dim s As String = "100950-100999"

Debug.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.Length - 3))
```

Output:

> 999

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Strings.Right(string, n)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the last `n` characters of `string`:

> Returns a string containing a specified number of characters from the right side of a string.